# In Windows, the http.sys component rejects any incoming post requests that do not include a 'Content-Length' header

Tags: iis, http.sys

How is it possible to ignore the Content-Length header validation check for incoming requests of the HTTP.sys component?

I have not found any way to ignore the Content-Length header validation check of the HTTP.sys component. It appears to be a native component that cannot be modified, which means that the validation check cannot be disabled or bypassed for incoming requests.

Comment: In the modern world, applications must adhere to open standards (HTTP for example) to communicate with each other. So, you shouldn't expect much support when someone tries to break the rules. Ask whoever generates those faulty requests to fix on their side.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible in iis, the Content-Length header is mandatory for messages with entity bodies.

Comment: @LexLi I appreciate your prompt response. However, I regret to inform you that requesting the client to modify their code is not an option in this scenario. Although it would be the ideal solution, it's unfortunately not feasible at this time.

Given this constraint, I'm seeking alternative solutions to bypass the validation check. Can you please provide suggestions or recommendations for potential workarounds?

My project is an ASP.NET Core app that is hosted on IIS 10. 

Any insights you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @samwu thank you for your response. The weird thing is that this is possible for IIS 8.5 but not possible for IIS 10. It seems that in IIS 10, this was fixed as part of some security improvements.

Comment: Can you show me how this is done in IIS 8.5? what function is used? is there no such function in iis10?